vscode RUN AND DEBUG
what are the following two configurations in the vscode RUN AND DEBUG:

(lldb) Launch
C/C++: clang++ build and debug active file

They seems to be there by default and I could not remove them. If I try to run it, I get the error: "Default config not found in provideDebugConfigurations()".
Please see the attached image.

In the picture, I added the configuration "C++ Launch". The other two were there and I do not know how to use them.
